# What is a diffrent when i call the class with brackets and when without?

Tags: less

What is the difference between when I call the class with brackets and then without them?

I have the .clearfix class from the bootstrap 3.x

What I should I use ?

```
.a {
    .clearfix;
    //or ?
    .clearfix();
}
```

There is any different way for the less compiler ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference, from LESS documentation:

> Notice that when you call the mixin, the parentheses are optional.

```
// these two statements do the same thing:
.a(); 
.a;
```